# execute python script with shell script - variables determined in sh

Tags: python, bash

I have determined variables in the shell script and now I would like to implement these variables for the execution of python script
 (python script requires variables determined within the shell script).

--------------------------- shell_script.sh--------------------------

# variables a and b are required for execution of my_pythonscript.py

a=hvariable_1

b=variable_2

python my_pythonscript.py a b

---

many thanks for your help and suggestions in advance

Comment: I mean, unless I'm missing something, you basically have it. Command should just be `python my_pythonscript.py "$a" "$b"`.

Comment: its not working.
lets say that my_pythonscript.py : print(a+b)

Comment: "It's not working" isn't particularly helpful feedback. What's the traceback? Are you setting the variables within python as shown in either of the two answers?

Comment: It works as you recommended. I realized that I had an empty variable. Thank you for your generous help and sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

shell_script.sh

```
A='your variable'
B='another variable'
python my_pythonscript.py "$A" "$B"
```

my_pythonscript.py

```
import sys
a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]
```

**Please note:** `sys.argv[0]` is the script name, in your case `my_pythonscript.py`

Also if you intend to use python 3.6 use `python3 my_pythonscript.py a b`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass them to your script as argument variables:

Your shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

VARIABLE1='Hello'
VARIABLE2='World'

python example.py $VARIABLE1 $VARIABLE2
```

Your Python script:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 3:
    print(sys.argv[1] + ' ' + sys.argv[2] + '!')
```

The python script prints when run through shell script:

```
Hello World!
```